# Pandas dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe like :

```
COL1 VALUE1 VALUE2
 A      A12     1    
 B      B13     2 
 A      C12     3
 B      Q12     4
```

Need a dictionary from the above dataframe where COL1 will be stored as the key and value1 and value2 will be in sub-dict.

eg:-

```
dict = {'A':{'A12':1, 'C12':3}, B:{'B13':2, 'Q12':4}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) converted to `dict` `zip`ed columns and last convert [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('COL1').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.VALUE1, x.VALUE2))).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': {'C12': 3, 'A12': 1}, 'B': {'B13': 2, 'Q12': 4}}
```